# Assigning a property in a closure in Swift

Tags: swift, properties, closures

I have this piece of code I am not quite sure it works or creates a loop and that I cannot unfortunately test until the new Xcode comes out hopefully not failing any longer. Moreover I would also like to be clarified in theory:

```
private var pivotTitle:String?
var title: String?{
    get{
        guard let coordinate=delegate?.targetAnnotation?.coordinate else {return nil}
         let location=CLLocation (latitude:coordinate.latitude, longitude:coordinate.longitude)
            if self.pivotTitle==nil {
                ReferenceSingleton.sharedReferenceCounter().placemarkForLocation(location, completionHandler:{
                    (placemarks, error) in
                        if placemarks != nil && placemarks!.count > 0{
                            let placemark = placemarks![0];
                            if let address=placemark.addressDictionary?["Street"] as? String, self.delegate != nil {
                                self.pivotTitle=String(format:"%@: %@", address, Sharing.sharedSharing().routeNameForNumber(self.delegate!.type))
                            }
                    }
                })
            }
            return self.pivotTitle;
        }
}
```

What is your idea of this code? Would it be possible to get rid of the pivotTitle variable?

Comment: You can't make a computed property async

Comment: So I think the construct I built is the most appropriate one, do you confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to set a computed property asynchronously. You could set it inside a function though.

Comment: Of course, yet, as you may see, I calculate the property in the closure but I assign the value to another private variable to return it. Why should not this work?

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci - Because it will run asynchronously, and thus you'll immediately return the previous value of this private stored property, not the one you set inside the completion handler of that asynchronous method. I presume your intent was to return the updated value, which you cannot do (or not without making this synchronous with semaphores and the like, which would be a very, very bad idea).

Comment: @Rob Yes, exactly. And yes, using semaphores on a computed property would be a terrible idea since they would block the main thread. So, maybe get rid off the computed property and make it into a non-computed property.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up classicly putting the call in the init and assigning the property in the closure from there, letting go of the computed property.